# All roots of the polynomial $x^n +a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + a_{n-2} x^{n-2}+...+a_1 x+a_0$ lie in the interval $(0,1)$. Prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} k a_{k}>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The polynomial $x^n +a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + a_{n-2} x^{n-2}+...+a_1 x+a_0$ has $n$ distinct real roots in the interval $(0,1)$ where $n\geq 3$.

Prove that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} ka_{k} \gt 0$$

My Attempt:
I tried using Cauchy Schwarz inequality but it isn't working out

Comment: Several solutions on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h605367p3596093, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h567870p3328850 found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn-2%7D%20ka_%7Bk%7D%3E0%24)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Inequality $\bf1$**

For $a_k\gt0$, if $|S|\ge2$, then
$$
\prod_{k\in S}(1-a_k)\gt1-\sum_{k\in S}a_k\tag1
$$
$(1)$ follows by induction using $(1-a)(1-b)=1-a-b+ab\gt1-(a+b)$.

---

**Answer**

Let
$$
\begin{align}
p(x)
&=x^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kx^k\tag{2a}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n(x-r_k)\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
p'(x)
&=nx^{n-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}ka_kx^{k-1}\tag{3a}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\prod_{k\ne j}(x-r_k)\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$
The question is equivalent to showing
$$
\begin{align}
p'(1)
&\gt n+(n-1)a_{n-1}\tag{4a}\\
&=n-(n-1)\sum_{k=1}^nr_k\tag{4b}
\end{align}
$$
Since
$$
p'(1)=\sum_{j=1}^n\prod_{k\ne j}(1-r_k)\tag5
$$
we need to show
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n\prod_{k\ne j}(1-r_k)\gt n-(n-1)\sum_{k=1}^nr_k\tag6
$$
However, if $n\ge3$, Inequality $1$ implies
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n\prod_{k\ne j}(1-r_k)
&\gt\sum_{j=1}^n\left(1-\sum_{k\ne j}r_k\right)\tag{7a}\\
&=n-(n-1)\sum_{j=1}^nr_j\tag{7b}
\end{align}
$$